# Limiting numbers without if statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, if-statement

I was curious if there is a way to limit a number with javascript without using if statements. Say I have a number that goes from 0 to 100, but I only want it to allow 30 to 70. So anything less than 30 became 30 and anything greater than 70 became 70. With if statements it would look like this:

```
var x = 0;
if (x > 70) {
   x = 70;
}
if (x < 30) {
   x = 30;
}
```

I'm looking more for a solution involving arithmetic.

Comment: Any particular reason for not liking if statements? If it's speed, then things are a bit more complicated in javascript. If it's aesthetics, then I'd go with the min+max answer from @strah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can do it with the conditional ternary operator (`.. ? .. : ..`), but I assume that you are asking about just doing it with math only, no conditionals.  If so, then you can do it with an Absolute function:

```
var x30 = x - 30;
var x30 = (x30 + Math.abs(x30)) / 2  + 30;
var x70 = 70 - x;
var x70 = 70 - (x70 + Math.abs(x70)) / 2;
```

Comment: Yes, this seems like the solution that I'm looking for.

Comment: This is not clear code. All those arithmetic operations are just discarding precision, and the final value which has been limited to within the range is not even given here. Min+max is a far simpler, clearer and better approach.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
x = Math.min(70, Math.max(30, x));
```

Comment: This is probably the clearest and least complicated approach, and the one that I would use.

Answer (score 2):

There's always ternary expressions ?

```
var x = 0;
    x = x > 70 ? 70 : x;
    x = x < 30 ? 30 : x;
```

You can even join them

```
var x = 0;
    x = x > 70 ? 70 : x < 30 ? 30 : x;
```

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of a solution using arithmetic.

Comment: How exactly would you calculate something like that without just using conditions and greater/lesser than? There's some math functions that could be used, but it's not "better" or more efficient, quite the contrary?

Comment: It's more of a hypothetical question than that of efficiency. I probably should have been more specific in my post. Apologies.

Comment: Well, then it's not really a javascript question anymore, but a question on how to do basic range mathematics ?

Comment: Yeah, but that still uses the Math object, and is no better than the answers using Math.min / max, it can of course be done without using the Math object as well, with just basic math, and a search on Google will probably give you an equation that works, I just don't see the point ?

Comment: There was no mention in the question about not using the Math object; the OP just wanted to know if it could be done without conditionals. Completely different.

Comment: @EmmyS - I was just answering the comment above by RBarry, saying his answer was no better than the other answers using the Math object, I did'nt say using the Math object was a no-no, but the answer by strah uses the Math object in a much cleaner way, and is IMO better. The Math object only contains some basic math, so it could have been done without the Math object all together as well, but there's just no reason to do so, so I still don't see the point?

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional (ternary) operators and chain them like so

```
var x = 0;
x = x > 70 ? 70 : x < 30 ? 30 : x;
```

Not sure how readable this is though :)

Altenratively, you could use Math.min() and Math.max()

```
var x = 0;
x = Math.max(30, Math.min(x, 70));
```

Answer (score 0):

### Short circuiting

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)

x = x > 70 ? 70 : (x < 30 ? 30 : x);
```

Single line, no if statments.

### Or you can use max/min

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)

x = Math.min(70, Math.max(30, x));
```